# Fill map infoWindow with the data of a ParseUser in android

Tags: android, parsing, infowindow

I'am having problems when filling an infoWindow of a map with data from a ParseUser. I have the objectId from the ParseUser as the title of the marker. Then when clicking on the marker, I want to display an infowindow filling its contents with data from that parseUser. I get the ObjectId from the marker title and then a I do a findInBackground.

This is the code inside the infowindow:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
        R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
        title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.restaurantName);
        String objectId = marker.getTitle();
        ParseQuery < ParseUser > query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("restaurant", true);
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", objectId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback < ParseUser > () {
            public void done(List < ParseUser > objects,
            ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (objects.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
                            ParseObject p = objects.get(i);
                            title.setText(p.getString("restaurantname"));
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    title.setText("merda mes gran");
                }
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
});
```

The problem comes when I click on the marker and nothing is displayed inside the infowindow. I think that the problem is in the search of the user and accessing to the data I want, because when I do not do this search and set the title text manually, then I have the text I want in the infowindow when clicking the marker.

I also have tried to change the way of accessing to the item in te objescts list inside the FindCallback but every way has the same result: nothing is displayed in the infowindow.

Comment: Hey, I realize this is a bit late but from Google's Info Window docs (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows), you need to call `showInfoWindow()` after you make changes/updates to the view (e.g., `setText()`), since it's actually drawn as a Bitmap, not a live view like normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am not going to use an infowindow. I solved it using a fragment that appears inside a FrameLayout when clicking on a map marker.